# How to disable location service in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a Flutter source code. My code use **geocoding** and **geolocator** plugin for location services.

But my app won't need to access user's location so I want to disable this function.

Can you tell me how to remove location completely in the app? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the package from pubspec.yaml. Check info. Plist and remove all location based keys. Check Android manifest and delete all location based keys here too

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove any permissions that exist from AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Then delete the related classes or methods from the source code.